# Optimized conversion of many PDF files to PNG if most of them have 90% the same content

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, png

I'm using ImageMagick to convert a few hundred thousand PDF files to PNG files.  ImageMagick takes about ten seconds to do this.  Now, most of these PDF files are automatically generated grading certificates, so it's basically just a bunch of PDF files with the forms filled in with different numbers.  There are also a few simple raster images on each PDF>  I mean, one option is to just throw computing power at it, but that means money as well as making sure they all end up in the right place when they come back.  Another option is to just wait it out on our current computer.  But I did the calculations here, and we won't even be able to keep up with the certificates we get in real-time.

Now, the option I'm hoping to pursue is to somehow take advantage of the fact that most of these files are very similar, so if we have some sort of pre-computed template to use, we can skip the process of calculating the entire PDF file every time the conversion is done.  I'd do a quick check to see if the PDF fits any of the templates, run the optimized conversion if it does, and just do a full conversion if it doesn't.

Of course, my understanding of the PDF file format is intermediate at best, and I don't even know if this idea is practical or not.  Would it require making a custom version of ImageMagick?  Maybe contributing to the ImageMagick source code?  Or is there some solution out there already that does exactly what I need it to? (We've all spend weeks on a project, then had this happen, I imagine)

Comment: How about showing us a couple of samples? Also, if they are certificates you have generated, do you have the text for each one in a database or file as it would be easy to generate a PNG from the text and a template. Another option is GNU Parallel to get all your CPU cores working on the problem at once - surpriringly easy...

Comment: Another option might be to use a Perl module to extract the text from each PDF and then use PerlMagick to put the text on a new PNG template. If you have a limited number of certificate templates, it'd probably be quite easy with PerlMagick to detect which one it was - by taking the average colour of the page.

Comment: Actually, these certificates are from a grading lab, and we don't generate them ourselves.  Obvious if we did, the solution would be trivial.  but I can give some examples.  They're diamond grading certificates.  We're a small jewelry company, but we're trying to list as many diamond certificates as possible for our customers, so they can buy diamonds all over the world for us to set.  Anyway, here are the PDF files:

https://enchanteddiamonds.com/certs/test/giacert.pdf

https://enchanteddiamonds.com/certs/test/twopagecert.pdf

Comment: Excellent, thank you. And can you click `edit` underneath your post and edit it to show the ImageMagick command you are currently using, and also the output of `identify -version`.

Comment: Why would you want to use ImageMagick? MuDraw (of [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/)) produces better quality PNG and is about 4 times faster, with your file. Second, you are right, both PDF files have constant 'templates' as `Form XObject` and only small and lightweight variable (I think) data, some text and images. So, if that's correct and all files are like that, it is possible to have set of templates as pre-made PNGs and then render only variable data and merge. Not sure if that'll be too much faster.

Comment: @VadimR In answer to your question, I would want to install ImageMagick because, on Mac OSX at least, MuPDF requires XQuartz which is obsolete.

Comment: @VadimR When analyzing the performance of the conversion, Ghostscript was using the majority of the CPU cycles, so I don't think using a different image processor would affect performance very much.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have had a look at this. I took your `PDF` and converted it to a `JPEG` like this - till you tell me the actual parameters you prefer.

```
convert -density 288 image.pdf image.jpg
```

and it takes 8 seconds and results in a 2448x3168 pixel JPEG of 1.6MB - enough for a page size print.

Then I copied your file 99 times so I had 100 PDFs, and processed them sequentially like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for p in *.pdf; do
   echo $new
   new="${p%%pdf}jpg"
   convert -density 288 $p $new
done
```

and that took 14 minutes 32 seconds, or average of 8.7 seconds.

Then I tried using GNU Parallel to do exactly the same 100 PDF files, like this:

```
time parallel -j 8 convert -density 288 {} {.}.jpg ::: *.pdf
```

keeping all 8 cores of my CPU very busy. but it processed the same 100 PDFs in 3 minutes 12, so averaging 1.92 seconds each, or a 4.5x speed-up. I'd say well worth the effort for a pretty simple command line.

Depending on your preferred parameters for `convert` there may be further enhancements possible...

Comment: Awesome!  However, I was currently running the script on an Amazon EC2 cloud machine.  Maybe there's some Amazon service that lets you run on ten cores or something.  I suppose I need to look into that.  Also, I'm most comfortable using Ruby, since our website uses Rails and the RMagick gem lets you get a lot of image information directly, using Ruby methods.

Comment: The commands I was running to generate the PNG image that I ended up using was this:

`convert -density 200 -crop '100%x50%+0+0' ./giacert.pdf PNG8:./giacert.png`

`convert -density 200 ./twopagecert.pdf[0] PNG8:./giacerttype2.png`

I should look more into using Amazon's processing services for this, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case ended up being to use MuPDF (thanks @Vadim) from the command line, which is about ten times faster than GhostScript (the library used by Imagemagick).  MuPDF fails on about 1% of the PDF files though, due to improper formatting, which GhostScript is able to handle reasonably well, so I just wrote an exception handler to only use Imagemagick in those cases.  Even so, it took about 24 hours on an 8-core server to process all the PDF files.